# Use of 'happen to'

Tags: grammar

> When I was passing through the forest, I happened to see a herd of deer.

I have to identify which part of this sentence has an error. The book where I found it says using 'happen to' is the error here, but doesn't explain enough. As a result of which, I am confused. Using 'happened to' doesn't seem wrong to me. Can someone help me out?

Comment: If you find out, explain it to us.

Comment: Using 'happened to'  in that sentence does not sound wrong to me.

Comment: About the only thing I can see that one might argue over is the comma.  Some folks would leave it there, others would remove it.  Well, that and the use of "When" rather than "As".

Comment: _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (201) includes this definition of _happen_ as a transitive verb: "**2.** To have the fortune (to be or do something); be in a situation or position (to be or do something): _The bus station happens to be close to the museum. I happen to know the answer to that question._" The person in your example sentence had the fortune or was in a situation or position to see a herd of deer; therefore, according to AHDEL, using _happened_ in place of one of those other formulations is idiomatically correct.

Comment: Please edit your question and identify the title and author.